# Boosting the sxa search result by multilist field values

Tags: sxa, solr, sxa-search, boosting

I have a requirement where I have to boost the items in search result based on a multilist field values of the item. I have already added the target value of those multilist values to the Index using the below config.

```
<field fieldName="servicesprovided" returnType="stringCollection" type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.ResolvedLinks,  Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search" referenceField="services" contentField="title"/>
```

Below are issue i am experiencing.

- Rule **where** the **services_sm** field is **case-insensitively equal to** Search Box query - is **NOT** working as expected.
- Rule **where** the **services_sm** field **is equal to** Search Box query - is working only when the entered case is same as the case of field value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood after analyzing the solr log and search over web that the boosting works case insensitively if the returnType is textCollection instead of string collection.
The 'Services' field is a Tag Treelist and hence updating the return type for the same as textCollection in the config file fixed the issue.